# Folder/files access permission

Tags: domain, directory, permissions

I have office laptop registered into domain (wins server 2003) used by Bill with several access to folder/files in server, then Bill replaced by other staff, Mark. Laptop used by Bill are now used by Mark. We setup his name as new member in our domain server.

The problem are, Mark unable to access files/folders in server even I gave him the same right and permission on server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of permissions you are mixing, the one type "group membership" is what you copied from the user bill to the new user mark, however there is also the "file permissions" which may be set with access to the user Bill, and not the group where both users are member off. You will need to manually check the files and change the permissions (maybe on the parent folder) to allow the proper group to have access in order to let Mark use this.

Comment: I do add both Bill and Mark in same group (Finance) with same permission and right. But Mark cannot create folder and copy file in same folder in server.

Comment: Right click the folder where the problem occurs, select 'properties' and go to the 'security' tab. on there it shows which users/groups have what rights on that folder. obviously the finance group in this case will need at least read and write access (change). if this is indeed incorrect you can also recursively overwrite any other access rights below with the "advanced" button and selecting the check mark at the bottom to overwrite any access properties.

Comment: I do exactly as you said but nothing changes. I also reboot the server for hoping permissions changes but still nothing changes. any way, thanks, for the quick response from you.

Comment: Under the same advanced button, there is also a tab called "effective permissions" which as an administrator lets you input a username/group to check the actual permissions that user or group has on that folder. Also make sure there are no "DENY" permissions on any of the groups and users in the folder which might mess up the end result (DENY>ALLOW)

Comment: This is what I do: I right click on folder (Finance) then - Properties, then click Advanced button below. Other windows appeared with Permission, Auditing, Owner and Effective Permissions Tab. No other tab appeared.